# Tehilim divided over thirty days - when there are only 29 days

Tags: tehilim-psalms

In most Tehilim's there is a division of the tehilim for thirty days. What does one do in a month that has 29 days? Do you say the Tehilim for the 30th day, on the 29th of that month, or on the 1st of the new month?

Comment: I've no source, but anecdotally I know at least some people say the last two days' on day 29.